# ASP.NET Form app not rendering continuously

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, wcf

I'm writing a simple winforms app in C# that connects to an ashx file which has JSON updating every 1 second.  My app needs to call this file, gathering data and display it on my aspx page.

The requirements are that I have one button to start the process.  When the button is pressed one instance of the data displays as it should.  The problem is when I try to do it multiple times.

```
  protected void eThorButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        //{
            RenderData(eThorButton.Text);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        //}

    }

    private void RenderData(string buttonText)
    {
       EquationData deserializedData = getData("http://test.com/test.ashx");

            var processed = new ProcessEquation();
            int result = processed.Calculate(deserializedData);

            string res = deserializedData.parm1 + "  " + deserializedData.op + "  " + deserializedData.parm2 +
                " = " + result;
            TextBoxResult.Text = res;

            equation.Append("  " + deserializedData.parm1 + "  " + deserializedData.op + "  " + deserializedData.parm2 +
                " = " + result + '\n');
            TextAreaResults.Value = equation.ToString();
    }
```

What I want is for each record to render as I loop through the data, pausing for one second before continuing.  What actually happens is the loop finishes first and then renders all five records at the same time.

How can I modify my code to display each record, one second apart?

thanks

---

I created an ajax enabled WCF service:

```
namespace CandidateTest.Service
```

{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "CandidateTest.Service")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class eThorService
    {
        public string button;
        [WebGet()]
        [OperationContract]
        public void getUpdate()
        {
            _Default def = new _Default();

```
        def.RenderData(button);
    }
}
```

}

and a script to call 'getUpdate'

```
$(function () {

while ($('#eThorButton').text != "Stop") {

    $.ajax({

        url: 'Service/eThorService.svc/getUpdate',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err);
        }

    })
    delay(1000);
}
```

});

This is based on research online.  This is my first attempt at doing this so I don't really know what I'm doing.  The service runs from the browser when I enter the URL but it doesn't appear to be being called from my script.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you put it in the browser, you are putting the full url, right? Try putting that full url in the `url:` part.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting how the page lifecycle works.  Your `eThorButton_Click` event handler finishes before any HTML is sent back to the browser to be rendered.

If you want to see data change on your page live, you need to use javascript on the client to make a request back to the server to get the update for that second.  I would make a new webservice that calls your `RenderData` function and returns the `equation.ToString()` result.  Then have javascript calls this webservice.  When it gets the result, append it to a `<div/>` to display it.

Comment: I've been modifying my code all morning without much sucess.  I added an ajax enabled WCF service and a jquery script to call my RenderData method.  The service is working from entering the url in my browser but it appears my script isn't.  Let me add the code here....